# Flash client and HTTP connection with server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Can a flash client program communicate with a server using HTTP connection like it would do in a JAVA-oriented fashion:

```
String URLS = "http://" + s.getHostName()
+ ":8888/Producer/getItems";
try {
URL url = new URL(URLS);

InputStream is = url.openStream();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);

res = (Items[]) ois.readObject();
is.close();
ois.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it can. Check the [URLRequest](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) manual. And pay special attention to the security chapter that is linked from the manual.